# Why would the Superior [Species X] ever choose to work with humans?

Tags: society, interspecies-relations

[Species X] comes from an alternate dimension, and have come to inhabit medieval Earth. The members of this foreign species have incredibly long lifespans, heightened physical abilities and hardiness, as well as strong penchants for magic. It turns out that through a ‘fusing’ ritual with Species X (viable only with consent of individuals from Species X), humans are able to reap these superior qualities of Species X.

This of course, is beneficial to humans. By fusing, humans are able to gain security, magic, strength, and the consequential military and social prestige following these heightened abilities. However, from the viewpoint of Species X, this fusion has more negatives than positives. Species X tends to look down on consorting with the noisy, squabbling, short-lived humans and their funny antics and materialism. In addition, the ‘fusing’ process depletes Species X’s magic storage, and Species X’s social hierarchy is decided strictly on the amount of magical reserves each individual has.

Some members of [Species X] may choose to perform this ‘fusing’ ritual with humans out of pure curiosity and boredom. Or perhaps some members are human-philes, obsessed with human civilization and psychology. But why would a large percentage of Species X ever consent to work with and ‘fuse’ with humans?

Note: Fusing ritual is not all-or-nothing; individuals can fuse/ de-fuse as they wish. But why would they choose to fuse at all, and continuously so, in the first place?

Comment: you should probably go into more detail about what the result of fusing is.

Comment: Homo X is blessed the stomach to digest earthly food... and an "exit" to remove toxin and fats as excrement.

Answer (score 5):

You need the fusing to serve a necessary function for Species X, otherwise, you are relegated to a godlike species that really has no reason to be interested in the affairs of humans.  There are many ways to do this:

**Propagation of the Species**

Make Species X's fertility depend on them fusing with another sentient species.  In their fused state, members of Species X attain sexual maturity and are able to mate with one another.  Sexual intercourse in some human cultures is considered distasteful but necessary for the continuation of one's bloodline - give fusion a similar perception.

**Attainment of useful abilities**

Make fusion a two-way street.  Even if Species X is more advanced than humanity, is there anything humanity can do that Species X cannot?  The attainment of some useful ability, even from an inferior species, could still be incentive enough to undergo the process.

**Attainment/ease of survivability**

Foreign dimensions may have different physical rules than ours.  Fusion with humans may be necessary for the extra-dimensionals to stay in our dimension for any length of time.  It may also just make it more convenient by taking away the need for support machinery - convenient enough to bother.

**Avoiding genetic stagnation**

Allow the fusion process to involve some genetic manipulation for both parties.  By fusing with other races, your Species X is able to "reroll" some of their genetic material (doesn't have to be extensive), which promotes genetic diversity - crucial for a small population to produce healthy subsequent generations.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with why humans choose to do self destructive acts.

Addiction.
Revenge. 
Suicidal. 
Low self esteem.
Other ----

Brainstorm a few reasons why *we* do stupid things, and then see which can be modified for your super-beings. They must have a vulnerability somewhere, or they wouldn't be interesting. Use that.

Answer (score 2):

Fido, do my homework for me! No more eating it, Ok?

Humans can be helpful to Species X, more helpful than dogs are for humans. By "uplifting" humans, aliens can get very capable servants, or maybe just another set of very sympathetic eyes and ears.

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, the ‘fusing’ process depletes Species X’s magic storage, and Species X’s social hierarchy is decided strictly on the amount of magical reserves each individual has.
>
> But why would they choose to fuse at all, and continuously so, in the first place?

**It's an investment/trade**.
Species X is part of this dimension now,
and its members need resources from our dimension in order to survive and thrive.
What better way to get local resources than with the help of some influential locals?

You see, Species X don't just fuse with anybody: they fuse with members of the ruling class in exchange for unlimited access to desired resources.

"Hey, prince dealing with a major rebellion, I bring you an offer. I will fuse with you for a decade, and then for a week or two every year afterwards, and in exchange you give me all the food I want, a house near the strongest magical nexus in the kingdom, and a small force of servants."

Win-win. King guy now is an invincible battlemage when he needs to be, and the Species X thing now only has to "work" for two weeks a year.
The initial decade of fusion is a short time on the Species X timescale, so it's not that bad.

Species X may only care about magical reserves,
but **having more time and energy free for storing/finding magic is worth the time and energy expended while fused**.

Answer (score 2):

I can see several reasons.

1.**Creativity** Species X doesn't sound any smarter than humans, if anything better physical abilities, magic, and longer lifespan may make less intelligent. humans have to solve problems the hard way, that makes us clever.

"I never would have thought of using magic to do that"

more observant X would realize the benefit of a more flexible thinker. Heck just having an additional perspective may be a huge advantage.

2.**Faster growth** If long lifespan also means slower maturation they may learn slower as well. 
Fusing with a human may take a while but you progress much faster after that, after a while the benefit far outweighs the penalty. This could work for power as well, sure it costs power but your power grows faster afterwards.

3.**Versatility** Maybe having two minds to focus on magic at the same time make your magic much more powerful or versatile, two minds focusing on the same thing could make it more powerful or alternatively each mind focusing on different things could allow you to do many more things with magic than X could do alone, magic goes from blunt instrument to precision machinery. Use music as an analogy no matter how good a person is they can't play the same music two people playing together can.

X may end up weaker but it doesn't matter because it is the difference between gunpowder in a pile on the ground vs gunpowder in a gun, power focused and controlled gives far more bang for your buck.

4.**Addiction** Maybe human emotions are addictive, like caffeine or tobacco, or maybe it is like spicy food where giving it up makes everything taste like cardboard. Life just is not as exciting without being fused to one of those live fast/die young monkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Ties to the history of Species X

There is an old wise mans tale where there existed a old ancient tree which had grown for a thousand years , and everyone in that community worshiped it and honored it for having superior features then all the other trees in the forest, its fruits where the most nourishing and where almost magical in that those who ate it achieved some sublime state, like some drug with no negative effects but artistic and engineering inspiration , each night somebody had to guard it, and the guard of night X decided that he was going to cut down the branches of the tree in one quick swoop with some advanced mechanical tool while everybody slept, nobody would suspect any guard from their community to do this because of the positive effects this tree gave to the community , but nevertheless he went ahead and did it anyway

what they discovered that actually , the secret of the tree was not on its surface but in its roots the next morning when they found the tree, and the benefits of the roots juices were far greater then its fruit

also they discovered that when it regrew back, it tripled in size and also accelerated its regrowth rate just because it was cut

This species of yours could have the same plot, the fact that they came across humans shows that they were not satisfied, like us with out technologies, they are great but we always realize that it is not enough, we still have unsolved problems and each time it feels like we hit a brick wall when we conquer them

so this species X of yours, could actually "accidentally" discover something they hadn't know or hadn't thought about before, by some accidental occurrence and it leads to new discoveries and new branches growing which didnt grow before as well as finding something new underneath the surface which was taken as the root before

Answer (score 1):

They could be raising an army. If a superior species were to enhance humanity with superhuman abilities they might still fall short of the superior super species, but still be useful. Especially if the superior species can enhance a lot of humans.

Answer (score 1):

**Incarnations.**

Your beings are potentiality.  The have strength, longevity and magic but they are not of this world.  Your beings do not only fuse with humans.  Humans hosts are one out of many.  Each host brings with it new perspective and a unique place in the world.  Your beings experience each way to exist, one after the other until the end of their time.

*I have lived through life in many forms.
 I have been man and
beast, sea and sky.*

http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2014/03/the-book-of-conquests.html

> In Irish mythology Tuan mac Cairill was a recluse who retains his
>   memories from his previous incarnations, going back to Antediluvian
>   age. Initially a follower of Partholon, he alone survived the plague
>   (or the Flood[1]) that killed the rest of his people. Through a series
>   of animal transformations he survived into Christian times, and told
>   the story of the Lebor Gabála Érenn,[2] from his people onward to St.
>   Finnian of Moville.[3][4] His legend is found in an 11th Century
>   manuscript called Lebor na hUidre (The Book of Dun Cow).[5] Tuan who
>   was a hermit or recluse, told St. Finnan that he was born 2000 years
>   earlier and witnessed many of the waves of invaders who came to
>   ancient Ireland - the Nemedians, Fir Bolg and the Tuatha De Dannan. As
>   a lone human guarding the land, he grew hairy, clawed and gray. And he
>   witnessed the invasion of Nemed (whom he says was his father's
>   brother), and woke up one day to find himself reborn as a vigorous
>   young stag.[6] The ancient stag watched the Nemedians perish, and was
>   again reborn into a young wild boar, and became the king of the
>   boar-herds, witnessing the taking of Ireland by Semion, leader of the
>   Fir Bolg.[7] Then he became a great hawk (or eagle[8]) and saw Ireland
>   seized by the Tuatha Dé Danann and the sons of Míl. Later reincarnated
>   into a salmon, he was caught by a fisherman serving a chieftain called
>   Cairill, and was eaten whole by the Cairill's wife, and passed into
>   her womb to be reborn again as Tuan mac (son of) Cairill.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuan_mac_Cairill

> Then old age came upon me, and my mind was sad, and I was unable to 
>   do all that I used to do before, but was alone in dark caves and in
>   hidden cliffs. Then I went to my own dwelling always. I remembered
>   every shape in which I had been before. I fasted my three days as I
>   had always done.
>
> I had no strength left. Thereupon I went into the shape of a large
>   hawk. Then my mind was again happy. I was able to do anything. I was
>   eager and lusty. I would fly across Ireland ; I would find out
>   everything.

http://sejh.pagesperso-orange.fr/keltia/version-en/tuan-en.html

Answer (score 1):

### For Political Advantage

A good place to look for why this might be advantageous for Species X might be political marriages. Sure, fusing with just one human is probably kind of a raw deal - human rises up, but you're stuck glued to this ape, *and* you're burning precious magic power. Worse, while you're off fraternising with the natives, your rival Y is amassing more magic!

On the other hand, what if you fused with, oh, let's say the local count's son? Why, the count would be thrilled! And now that you're technically kin, it's in the best interests of the family to march an army over and burn down Y's castle. Or lock them out of the trade market. Or any number of other advantages they have control over.

But that's thinking small. What if you're already pretty powerful - giving that up just for an alliance would be bad. But that also means you probably have some subordinates too. What if, rather than personally fusing with all the people you want as allies, you asked some of your subordinates to take the plunge? It doesn't matter that they lose a bit of personal power, because as a group now you're much more powerful and as your loyal subjects they're definitely tops in your book.

And once you have power in the form of allies and wealth and information, it's a short road to getting access to the things you really care about - magical sites, magical artifacts, rare discoveries, and so on.